GraphQL schema file error: "id field is not of type Boolean"
I'm defining my data model in the schema.graphql file for my Flutter app, seemingly without any syntax errors and following the rules of GraphQL v2, but then when I try to push the changes (amplify push) I get the following error: "id field is not of type Boolean".
A screenshot of my Terminal: The command "amplify push" has been entered, and the terminal returns the error "id field is not type Boolean"
I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I believe with GraphQL transformer v2 the id field should be type ID! as I've made it, but the error is suggesting that there's- what, a mismatch between the expected field type for the id field in one of my models?
I wish to push my changes to Amplify, but I cannot, until this error is solved.
Here's the code in question (aka the schema.graphql file), containing my three models:
type UserAuthInfo
  @model # In Amplify: Create a DynamoDB table and a GraphQL API for the model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: public, provider: identityPool, operations: [create] } # Allow public sign-up
      { allow: owner, operations: [read, update] } # Users can view & edit only their own records
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [read, update, delete] } # Admins have full access
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  email: AWSEmail!
  password: String!
  username: String!
}

# User model
type User
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete] } # Only the owner can create, update, or delete their user record
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [create, update, delete] } # Admins can create, update, or delete any user record
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  username: String! @index(name: "byUsername", queryField: "userByUsername")
  email: AWSEmail!
  # Challenges created by the user:
  challenges: [Challenge]
    @hasMany(
      indexName: "byOwner" # Matches the index name in the Challenge model, allows querying challenges by owner
      fields: ["id"]
    )
}

# Challenge model
type Challenge
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      {
        allow: owner
        ownerField: "owner" # Use user ID for ownership tracking
        identityClaim: "sub" # Use the unique user ID (sub) from the identity provider
        operations: [create, update, delete]
      }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [create, update, delete] } # Allow admin to delete challenges
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  lifeAspects: [String!]!
  details: String
  startDate: AWSDate!
  targetDate: AWSDate
  reminderDetails: String
  associatedGoalId: ID! # Goal linked to challenge, if any
  isCompleted: Boolean! # Tracks if the challenge is completed
  owner: ID! # ID of user who created the challenge
  createdAt: AWSDateTime # Automatically managed field for creation time
  isClosed: Boolean  # Tracks if the challenge is closed
    @index(
      name: "byOwner"
      queryField: "challengesByOwner" # Allows querying challenges by user's owner field
      sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"]
    )
}

Any help would be appreciated.
